# Upload file to google drive with javascript from anonymous user

Tags: javascript, file, upload, google-drive-api

I want to allow my anonymous website's visitors to upload files to Google Drive on behalf of my application. In a new app console I spotted some sort of Browser key, can I use it to reach my goal?
Or maybe there are some other ways of doing this by using Cloud Storage or something?

I don't want to involve server-side authentication, I need a pure Javascript solution.

PS: This article (https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js) doesn't help, since it requires my users to have Google Account.

Screenshot of my API Console:

[image: Screenshot of my API Console]

Comment: any solution on the above mentioned issue?? so far?

Comment: @Airy I understood that you want to make users upload a file to your Google Drive using Javascript. If my understanding is correct, are these posts useful for your goal? [Ref1](https://github.com/tanaikech/AsynchronousResumableUploadForGoogleDrive), [Ref2](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/12/22/uploading-multiple-files-from-local-to-google-drive-using-google-apps-script/), [Ref3](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/08/13/uploading-file-to-google-drive-from-external-html-without-authorization/) In these cases, Google Apps Script is used. If those were not useful for your situation, I apologize.